# To laugh with art, and from art

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does the following context want to say:

1.the best thing for a comic artist is to see how people laugh watching his/her work.

or

1.the best way to define a comic artist is a person who laughs at art and also makes others laugh at art.

> Context:
>
> To laugh with art, and from art, may be the highest complement that
> you can give to a comic-oriented artist.
>
> ("Art and Laughter" by Sheri Klein)

Answer (score 1):

Although there's plenty of room for confusion, it fairly clearly means the first, "…the best thing for a comic artist is to see how people laugh watching his/her work"

At the same time, that should prolly be either"watching *him*/her work", ie, observing the artist in the process of working, or "looking at his/her work", ie regarding the result of his/her work, whether finished or in progress.

I've little idea how a "comic-*oriented* artist…" differs from a simple "comic artist" but even if Klein really meant "complement”, ie “make complete” and not the more obvious “compliment”, ie “say pleasing things about”, that hardly “define a comic artist…”